# End point :start meaning in Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Apache camel.
Please explain me what is the meaning of **iso** and **:start** (in below code snippet) in apache camel context xml file?
There is bean with id **iso** defined in camel-context.xml. But, if camel route **to endpoint** is referring to **iso** bean then  what is the meaning of :start?

```
<to uri="iso:start" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the book "Camel in Action", an endpoint URI is compose of three parts, which are: a scheme, a context path and options in forms of

```
<Scheme>:<Context Path>?<Options>
```

---

> The **scheme** denotes which Camel component handles that type of
>   endpoint

For example, if your scheme is `file`, then it is using camel defined file component. Base on [Camel Component List](http://camel.apache.org/components.html), `iso` is not a camel-defined component. Thus, it is most likely a user-defined component and its behavior depends on the java class behind the setting.

> The meaning of **context path** vary by scheme

The meaning of context path depends on the scheme in use. Take below 4 endpoint URI as example

```
file:path/to/file
ftp://localhost:21/path/to/file
jms:queue:this.is.a.queue.name
timer:t1
```

For file component, it act as a path. For ftp component, it act as authentication information and a path. For jms component, it act as queue name. For timer component, it act as route id.

So, the meaning of `start` in your endpoint depends on the `iso` component and you need to figure it yourself as `iso` component is not camel-defined component.